# Can't make iteration with #property strict

Tags: mql4, mql5, mqlwrite

I have this code working without error. Basically, this code is to show value of Moving Averages on five previous bars per 5 minutes. MA's current value is omitted.

```
int     TrendMinDurationBar = 5,
        SlowPeriod          = 14,
        FastPeriod          = 7;

void OnTick()
{
    if ( NewBar( PERIOD_M5 ) == true ) MA( PERIOD_M5 );
}

void MA( int TF )
{
    double Slow[], Fast[];
    ArrayResize( Slow, TrendMinDurationBar + 1 );
    ArrayResize( Fast, TrendMinDurationBar + 1 );

    for (  int i = 1; i <= TrendMinDurationBar; i++ )
    {      Slow[i] = NormalizeDouble( iMA( Symbol(), TF, SlowPeriod, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_OPEN, i ), Digits );
           Fast[i] = NormalizeDouble( iMA( Symbol(), TF, FastPeriod, 0, MODE_EMA, PRICE_OPEN, i ), Digits );
           Alert( "DataSlow" + ( string )i + ": " + DoubleToStr( Slow[i], Digits ) );
    }
}

bool NewBar( int TF )
{
    static datetime lastbar = 0;
           datetime curbar  = iTime( Symbol(), TF, 0 );

    if (  lastbar != curbar )
    {     lastbar  = curbar; return( true );
    }
    else                     return( false );
}
```

When **`#property strict`** is included, the code is only working once after compiled. After new bar on **`M5`** chart exist, it doesn't make any iteration.

What's the solution if I insist to use `#property strict`?

Answer (score 0):

### Welcome to another *`New`*-`MQL4.56789` Catch-22

My candidate from **`Help > MQL4 Reference > Updated MQL4`** 
is
this one ( column **`[New MQL4 with #property strict]`** )

> Functions of any type should return a value

and
one more to be reviewed,
code simply loses the logic even for **`static double`** alternative it would be extremely inefficient under these circumstances:

> Local arrays are released when exiting {} block

---

Comment: I did move local arrays into void OnTick() to prevent arrays released after exiting the block, it means void MA() not called by iteration, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you also change void to return some value as noted in Help:

Comment: I never try it because when I'm trying to use *#property strict* back again the code running well. I don't know what happened. This is so frustrating. Maybe if *#property strict* usage make stuck, then remove it for a while and after everything is running smooth, *#property strict* can be used again. Just like a reset button. I do thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: I'm  gonna write another question regarding the code above, hope you can give a little help. Thanks @user3666197

Comment: Well, MQL4, namely the "new"-MQL4 is really a challenge. On the other hand I do not consider the possibility of "on/off"-magic to be real for finite state machines ( the code/compiler ecosystems are ). Sometimes a "behind the curtain" update of MetaLang.exe / compiler syntax may appear, after which it is wise to re-read the documentation ( no relevant and serious delta-changes are published, afaik ). So, get ready and **pack a lot of patience :o)**

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly well with `#property strict` as an EA in MT4 Build 950.

Are you sure you are running it as EA and not as Script or Indicator?

Comment: this is more like a comment than an answr to the question

Comment: Suggestion to run the program as an EA instead of as Indicator or Script could be an answer to the problem. But you are right, it does look more like a comment due to the fact that we lack more information from the OP.